# Why is this freemarker code failing when there is a comma in the list?

Tags: list, dictionary, groovy, freemarker

I have a map that contains a list (all the values in the list are strings):

```
["diameter":["1", "2", "3"]]
["length":["2", "3", "4"]]
```

I iterate through it in freemarker:

```
<#list product.getSortedVariantMap.keySet() as variantCode>
    <#list product.getSortedVariantMap[variantCode] as variantValue>
```

This works fine. However if one of the strings contains a comma like this:

```
def returnValue = ["diameter":["3,5"]]
```

I get the following error:

```
?size is unsupported for: freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> list product.getSortedVariantMap[variantCode] as variantValue [on line 200, column 41 in product.htm]
```

I have no idea what the error could be, a comma in a string shouldn't create that error.

Comment: I think the issue may be how Freemarker is wrapping the bean returned from `product.getSortedVariantMap`. Can you give us an indication as to what Java reflection would see when analyzing the class returned by `getSortedVariantMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on FreeMarker configuration, but `product.getSortedVariantMap` most probably returns the method itself, not its return value. You should write `product.sortedVariantMap`. (Although I don't understand why it doesn't stop earlier, on `product.getSortedVariantMap.keySet()`. Maybe your example is not exactly what to run?)

Comment: `product.getSortedVariantMap` returns a map.  `product.getSortedVariantMap[variantCode]` is returning a method -- at least in some cases.  This depends on the value of `variantCode` but it's impossible to be more specific without the original poster providing more detail.